Angular: Module not found error from external js file
In my angular project, I added an external js file src/app/example.js and a typescript file src/app/example.d.ts. In the typescript file added export const getUpdate: () => {};
Now I get bunch of module not found error for example Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery-mousewheel' that comes from the example.js file. Is there a way to ignore all the errors from this external js file or any external js file?
